# Set JSON Input value Dynamic

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to set JSON value into Array List Dynamically. It's working as expected if it's constant value but how to set this value on the fly. Your response is highly appreciated.

I am getting JSON value from a URL like

```
 https://www.abc.test/test.json
```

**Entire Source Code**

```
https://github.com/bpncool/SectionedExpandableGridRecyclerView
```

__JSON Input: __

```
  {
  "objectsArray": [
    {
      "name": "Apple Products",
      "Data": {
        "type1": "iPhone",
        "type2": "iPad",
        "type3": "iPod",
        "type4": "iMac"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Companies",
      "Data": {
        "type1": "LG",
        "type2": "Apple",
        "type3": "Samsung"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Java Static Code**

```
ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new Item("iPhone", 0));
arrayList.add(new Item("iPad", 1));
arrayList.add(new Item("iPod", 2));
arrayList.add(new Item("iMac", 3));
sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.addSection("Apple Products", arrayList);
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new Item("LG", 0));
arrayList.add(new Item("Apple", 1));
arrayList.add(new Item("Samsung", 2));
sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.addSection("Companies", arrayList);
sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Just set the Parameters inside a loop that traverses an array and add items accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input `Json` structure has a small problem. It should contain an array of `JsonObject`s which each of them has `"name"` and `"Data"` attributes.

```
{
  "objectsArray": [
    {
      "name": "Apple Products",
      "Data": {
        "type1": "iPhone",
        "type2": "iPad",
        "type3": "iPod",
        "type4": "iMac"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Companies",
      "Data": {
        "type1": "LG",
        "type2": "Apple",
        "type3": "Samsung"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

• The structure of your `"Data"` is like a `Map`, so I model it as a `Map`.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ProductsResponse {

    @SerializedName("objectsArray")
    private List<MyObject> objectsArray;

    public List<MyObject> getObjectsArray() {
        return objectsArray;
    }

    public static class MyObject {

        @SerializedName("name")
        private String name;

        @SerializedName("Data")
        private Map<String, String> data;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Map<String, String> getData() {
            return data;
        }

    }

    public String serialize() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this, ProductsResponse.class);
    }

    public static ProductsResponse deserialize(String jsonString) {
        if (jsonString == null)
            return new ProductsResponse();
        else {
            return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, ProductsResponse.class);
        }
    }

}
```

• Its deserializing result is:

[image]

• Finally, you can fill your list as following:

```
ProductsResponse products = ProductsResponse.deserialize(jsonString);
for (MyObject myObject : products.getObjectsArray()) {
    ArrayList<Item> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : myObject.getData().entrySet()) {
        arrayList.add(new Item(entry.getValue(), i++));
    }
    sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.addSection(myObject.getName(), arrayList);
}
sectionedExpandableLayoutHelper.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for your write up. Tomorrow, I will try and let you know. Can you let me know what are all the  changes required in the GitHub code for dynamic changes.